# Exception 504 when registering the consumer

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I've been working with Symfony 2.7 and the [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle/) to handle some long processes asynchronously.
After facing the issue where the MySQL connection dies after a few minutes, I discovered [rabbitmq-cli-consumer](https://github.com/corvus-ch/rabbitmq-cli-consumer), a small app in Go that takes care of consuming the queue, and gives its content to a command.

In my case, I use it with this command: `./rabbitmq-cli-consumer -c configuration-stock.conf --include -V -e 'php app/console amqp:consume:stock --env=prod -vvv'`, with this configuration file:

```
[rabbitmq]
host = HOST
username = USERNAME
password = PASSWORD
vhost=/VHOST
port=PORT
queue=stock
compression=Off

[exchange]
name=exports
type=direct
durable=On

[queuesettings]
routingkey=stock
messagettl=10000
deadLetterExchange=exports.dl
deadLetterroutingkey=stock
priority=10
```

To handle errors, I intend to use RabbitMQ's `x-dead-letter-exchange` and `x-dead-letter-routing-key` configuration, to be able to retry the message later (in case something went temporarly wrong).

My issue is that, when I define my queues in RabbitMQBundle's configuration, rabbitmq-cli-consumer is unable to consume the queue, throwing this error:

```
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Connecting RabbitMQ...
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Connected.
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Opening channel...
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Done.
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Setting QoS... 
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Succeeded setting QoS.
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Declaring queue "stock"...
2018/04/23 11:35:54 Registering consumer... 
2018/04/23 11:35:54 failed to register a consumer: Exception (504) Reason: "channel/connection is not open"
```

Here is the configuration I use for RabbitMQBundle:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    producers:
        exports:
            connection: default
            exchange_options:
                name: 'exports'
                type: direct
        exports_dl:
            connection: default
            exchange_options:
                name: 'exports.dl'
                type: direct

    consumers:
        stock_dead_letter:
            connection: default
            exchange_options:
                name: exports.dl
                type: direct
            queue_options:
                name: stock.dl
                routing_keys:
                    - stock
                arguments:
                    x-dead-letter-exchange: ['S', 'exports']
                    x-dead-letter-routing-key: ['S', 'stock']
                    x-message-ttl: ['I', 60000]
            callback: amqp.consumers.exports.stock

    multiple_consumers:
        exports:
            connection: default
            exchange_options:
                name: 'exports'
                type: direct
            queues:
                stock:
                    name: stock
                    callback: amqp.consumers.exports.stock
                    routing_keys:
                        - stock
                    arguments:
                        x-dead-letter-exchange: ['S', 'exports.dl']
                        x-dead-letter-routing-key: ['S', 'stock']
```

Has anyone ever encountered something similar ? And how did you solve it ?